# Set Excel sheet as datasource to Gridview

Tags: c#, excel

I have the excel sheet, I want to keep it as datasource to the gridview. gridview will be  editable so whatever the data updated sholud be write to again in excel sheet with respected location in sheet.
How can I do this?

Comment: You need to tell us what language you are developing in.

Comment: i m using c# .net and asp.net3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Jet driver to select from the spreadsheet via OLEDB. Your spreadsheet will need to be laid out in a table-like fashion, and you can have some painful problems with type guessing, but this may work for your situation.

Connection string samples [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

Comment: Great ... Now i can load the data to gridview but now i want to write data whatever updated in grid to back Excel sheet . what should i hav e to do? I am using c# _ Asp.net 3.5 combination

Comment: It's been a long time since I used WebForms, but I imagine there's an UpdateCommand property on the GridView DataSource? You should be able to craft a query along the lines of "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Column1 = ?, Column2 = ? WHERE Column3 = ?" and map the parameters to gridview columns.

Comment: I should add - it's not usually a great idea to manipulate an Excel spreadsheet via a website, as Excel is inherently single-user and you'll run into problems if you have multiple web users attempting to access the same spreadsheet.

Comment: oh! Thanks for reply and suggestion Sam, Actually this application is for Admin of system who is single user.So i think i can avoid multiple access for same file. isn't it?